# Sort objects by using three properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm new to using Javascript and trying to sort the objects.

What i have is objects Player in array playerLst. Every Player has property name, score, coeficent and ratio and of course the place (from non-english speaking country, there's probably a better word for this, with place i describe his positsion in table, for example, first, second third or so).

So i would like to sort the players using their score, coeficent and ratio and depending on that they will get their place.

I think the easyest way is to do a little playthrough example:

```
Player1.name = A;
Player1.score = 5;
Player1.coeficent = 4;
Player1.ratio = "22:8";

Player2.name = B;
Player2.score = 5;
Player2.coeficent = 6;
Player2.ratio = "24:8";

Player3.name = C;
Player3.score = 6;
Player3.coeficent = 2;
Player3.ratio = "1:0";

Player4.name = D;
Player4.score = 4;
Player4.coeficent = 3;
Player4.ratio: "10:5";

Player5.name = E;
Player5.score = 4;
Player5.coeficent = 3;
Player5.ratio: "8:5";
playerLst = [Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5];
```

So currently as we can see that obvious winner is Player3 because he has the maximum amount of points. So Player3.place should be after sort = 1. Player 1 & Player 2 have equal score which means their coeficents will be measured. Player2 has higher coeficent so he gets .place = 2 and player 1 gets .place = 3. Now we still have two players, D & E, who have same score and coeficent so ratios will be measured. Player D has better ratio than E so player D gets .place = 4 and player E .place = 5.

I've dealt with this issue several hours now and my brain is melting, i have tried to do it with different for cycles but still ended up in some error. If someone could provide something useful i'd appreciate it. Thanks!

E2:
Added jsfiddle how the comparing should look like
http://jsfiddle.net/4ep7k7yf/

E3:

This is my function for comparing:

```
function suuremKuiTeine(player1,player2){
if (player1.punkte > player2.punkte){
    return 1;
}
else if (player2.punkte > player1.punkte){
    return -1;
}
else{ //scores are equal
    if (player1.koef > player2.koef){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (player2.koef > player1.koef){
        return -1;
    }
    else{ //coeficents are equal
        ratio1 = player1.suhe;
        ratio_split = ratio1.split(":");
        ratio1 = parseInt(ratio_split[0])-parseInt(ratio_split[1]);
        ratio2 = player2.suhe;
        ratio_split = ratio2.split(":");
        ratio2 = parseInt(ratio_split[0])-parseInt(ratio_split[1]);
        if (ratio1 > ratio2){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (ratio2 > ratio1){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

}

With some alert magic i found that the ratios, score and coeficent are calculated correctly. However after the endless stream of alerts end

```
playerLst = playerLst.sort(suuremKuiTeine); //is global variable!
for (var i = 0; i<playerLst.length;i++){
    alert(playerLst[i].name);
}
```

The values are still the same. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your ratio is invalid in JavaScript (is it a fraction in your real code?) Also, use `.sort` (it takes a compartor).

Comment: It's actually a string, ratio 8:5 means +3, for example 7:9 means -2 and so on. It's a calculation i forgot to explain, sorry!

Comment: So put it as a string in your example. Also, can you write the logic of what's bigger between two elements (let's call them p1 and p2) - say a function `foo` that takes a player `p1` and a player `p2` and just returns 1 if p1 is bigger, 0 if they're equal and -1 if p2 is bigger? If you do that I can give you an answer :)

Comment: Umm, i think i might misunderstand you but at first the score is compared. If score is equal then the coeficent is compared. If one of them either p1 or p2 has bigger score then one with the bigger score is bigger. If coeficent is equal then ratio is compared. If it's not equal then one with the bigger coeficent is bigger. Ratio can be made into integer with simple res = player.coeficent.split(:) and ratio = parseInt(res[0])-parseInt(res[1]). Then the ratios can be compared in the same way as coeficent and score. If three properties - scrore, coeficent and ratio are equal then p1,p2 are equal.

Comment: That's great now write a _function in JavaScript_ that does this - you can post it on http://jsfiddle.net and then I'll add an answer, the function should take two players and just say which of them is bigger, basedo n the logic you posted above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ep7k7yf/ added fiddle

Comment: Awesome, now call `playerLst.sort(biggerThanOther)` where you switch `return player1` for `return 1`, `return player2` for `return -1` and `return "they're equal"` for `return 0` and see that it works :)

Comment: Changed it, should i just call it in a manner playerLst.sort(biggerThanOther) without any parameters (p1,p2)? If so then it didn't work i guess.

Comment: Make a fiddle of you calling it this way.

Comment: If i use the function i created with parameters playerLst[0] and playerLst[1] it displays a correct value. However doing with .sort() the list will stay the same.

Comment: Show me the code (jsfiddle), you need to return `-1` `0` and `1` like I said, read my previous comment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/md8xywt7/ this is jsfiddle. In my own code i'm using Estonian variables just for my own clarification.

Comment: You're not defining playerLst there anywhere...

Comment: It's global variable